# Jquery Mobile Ajax Post Insert Data

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to post data from a form with an ajax post. Currently I am just debugging this by alerting the data sent, via a php script.

So my code html :

```
       <form id="form_sewa">
            <input type="hidden" name="penyewaan" id="penyewaan" value="">
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <label for="nama_anak">Nama Anak:</label>
                <input type="text" data-mini="true" name="nama_anak" id="nama_anak" value="">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <label for="jumlah_uang">Jumlah Uang:</label>
                <input type="number" data-mini="true" name="jumlah_uang" pattern="[0-9]" id="jumlah_uang" value="">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <label for="harga_kamar"><b>Harga</b> Kamar:</label>
                <input type="number" data-mini="true" name="harga_kamar" pattern="[0-9]" id="harga_kamar" value="">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <!-- Untuk tanggal -->
                <label for="tanggal_masuk">Tanggal <b>Masuk:</b></label>
                <input id="tanggal_masuk" name="tanggal_masuk" data-mini="true" />
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <label for="tanggal_keluar">Tanggal <b>Keluar:</b></label>
                <input id="tanggal_keluar" name="tanggal_keluar" data-mini="true" />
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <label for="no_kamar"><b>Nomor</b> Kamar:</label>
                <input type="number" data-mini="true" name="no_kamar" pattern="[0-9]" id="no_kamar" value="">
            </div>
            <input type="submit" data-role="button" data-theme="f" data-inline="true" data-icon="check" id="submitSwa" />
            <a href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="f" data-inline="true" data-rel="back">Kembali</a>
        </form>
```

In JavaScript

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#submitSwa").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost/apri2/php/crudpenyewaan.php",
                type: "post",
                cache:false,
                data: {
                    nama_anak: $('#nama_anak').val(),
                    jumlah_uang: $('#jumlah_uang').val(),
                    harga_kamar: $('#harga_kamar').val(),
                    tanggal_masuk: $('#tanggal_masuk').val(),
                    tanggal_keluar: $('#tanggal_keluar').val(),
                    no_kamar: $('#no_kamar').val()
                },
                success: function(response){
                    alert(response);
                },
                error: function(){                      
                    alert('Error while request..');
                },
                complete: function() {
                    $.mobile.loading("hide");
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

And in php

```
<?php 
    print_r($_POST);    
?>
```

I have tried methods like submithandler, formdata serialize, but the alert doesn't show up and my url looks like this after clicking submit:
[image: Before submit]
[image: After submit]

Comment: I think `$("submitSwa")` needs to be `$("#submitSwa")`

Comment: I doubt your jquery click function gets executed

Comment: Thank you sir, I had change it, but the alerts didn't show up. @Akintunde-Rotimi

Comment: try adding to the form data-ajax="false"

Comment: Here is the the complete workflow description (plus some PHP/JS code) to achieve what You need: [Secure log on form - Hashing passwords in JavaScript before submitting](http://zoszsoz.blogspot.com/2011/04/secure-log-on-form-hashing-passwords-in.html) Please be aware that the article is dated 2011 so You'll have to fix it in some parts.